# What constitutes a "software installation" on a Windows 8/10 machine?

Tags: windows-10, windows-8, security, administrator

I have admin rights on my machine, so I never have any problem installing software. However, we have some new employees coming to our company that will not have admin rights and will not be able to install software and I am trying to figure out exactly what that means.

For example, some programs are just exe files. You copy to the machine and run them, so there is no "installation" process. At what point does this become blocked for a non-admin user? Does it mean they try to run the EXE and it says "you are not authorized to run executables" or something like that? So, basically every executable on the machine is marked somehow as being ok to run, is that how it works?

What if its a script or a Java program? For example, let's say they have Python or Java installed. I assume they can run Python files (.py) and java class files (.class) even though those are "programs", or no?

Answer (score 2):

If they are not administrators, then they cannot elevate programs. Where you would see a User Account Control prompt and continue, they would be stopped; the UAC dialog would prompt for an administrator's password.

Most large software programs require administrator rights to install because they write to protected locations like Program Files. Your non-administrative users would not be able to install these programs. "Installers" that just unpack a bunch of files to a given location might not need administrative privilege, and your users would be able to use these as normal.

Scripts, like all code, run under processes in Windows; each process has security attributes. You as an admin can run Python scripts with admin powers because you can elevate the Python process, but your new users will not be able to elevate, so while they can run the code, any attempted administrative operations would simply fail.

For completeness's sake, it's worth noting that technologies like [AppLocker](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd759117) can further restrict which programs a user can run, and these restrictions are generally based on characteristics of the program. Usually, though, that's not in play.

In summary, it's not an issue of "is this program an installer" - what matters is the ability to elevate to administrator.